# Solving a numbrix puzzle with Perl

Tags: perl

The task is to solve square numbrix puzzle. A numbrix puzzle consists of a field `n*n` and each cell can contain a number `1 -> n*n`. The task is to solve the puzzle and create a path from the cell with number `1` to the cell with number `n*n`.
Example with solution:

```
... ... 017 ... ...
... 021 ... 023 ...
005 ... ... ... 013
... 003 ... 001 ...
... ... 009 ... ...
```

Solution:

```
019 018 017 016 015
020 021 022 023 014
005 004 025 024 013
006 003 002 001 012
007 008 009 010 011
```

My teacher has given us a file that contains some steps (printed by his solution perl program). But I can't figure the list reduction step.

What my teacher's program prints:

```
... ... 017 ... ...
... 021 ... 023 ...
005 ... ... ... 013
... 003 ... 001 ...
... ... 009 ... ...


1 | 2 < 3 | 4 < 5 > 6 | 7 < 8 < 9 > 10 | 11 < 12 < 13 > 14 | 15 < 16 < 17 > 18 | 19 < 20 < 21 | 22 < 23 > 24 > 25

1.1:      15 19 
1.2:      16 18 20
1.4:      16 18 22 24
1.5:      11 15 25 
2.1:      4 6 20
2.3:      16 18 20 22 24
2.5:      12 14 22 24
3.2:      2 4 6 20
3.3:      7 11 15 19 25 
3.4:      12 14 22 24
4.1:      2 4 6
4.3:      2 8 10
4.5:      12 14
5.1:      7
5.2:      2 8 10
5.4:      8 10
5.5:      7 11

1.1:      19
1.2:      18 20
1.4:      16 24
1.5:      15 25
2.1:      20
2.3:      16 18 20 22 24
2.5:      14 24
3.2:      4 6 20
3.3:      7 11 15 19 25
3.4:      12 14 24
4.1:      4 6
4.3:      2 8 10
4.5:      12
5.1:      7
5.2:      8
5.4:      10
5.5:      11

# cell(s) with only one candidate: (1.1=19) (2.1=20) (1.2=18) (4.5=12) (5.1=7) (5.2=8) (5.4=10) (4.3=2) (5.5=11)

019 018 017 ... ...
020 021 ... 023 ...
005 ... ... ... 013
... 003 002 001 012
007 008 009 010 011

1.4:      16 24
1.5:      15 25
2.3:    * 16 22 24
2.5:      14 24
3.2:    * 4
3.3:    * 15 25
3.4:    * 14 24
4.1:      4 6

# cell(s) with only one candidate: (3.2=4) (4.1=6)

019 018 017 ... ...
020 021 ... 023 ...
005 004 ... ... 013
006 003 002 001 012
007 008 009 010 011

1.4:      16 24
1.5:      15 25
2.3:      16 22 24
2.5:      14 24
3.3:      15 25
3.4:      14 24

# cell(s) with only one candidate: (2.3=22)

019 018 017 ... ...
020 021 022 023 ...
005 004 ... ... 013
006 003 002 001 012
007 008 009 010 011

1.4:      16 24
1.5:      15 25
2.5:      14 24
3.3:    * 25
3.4:    * 24

# cell(s) with only one candidate: (3.3=25) (1.5=15) (3.4=24) (1.4=16) (2.5=14)

019 018 017 016 015
020 021 022 023 014
005 004 025 024 013
006 003 002 001 012
007 008 009 010 011
```

What my solution can do:

I have a datastructure with keeps track of the cell (1.1 for example) and it's candidates. I can print out the first list.

What my problem is:

I don't understand how he can reduce the number of candidates per cell. For example: the first list says that the possible candidates for cell 1.1 are 15 and 19. (I have this whole list). But then suddenly he can reduce the list saying cell 1.1 can only contain the number: 19. How does he do this ? (I don't need any code, I don't understand the logic behind this reduction).

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking for code, just for logic. So this might be what you are looking for:
In order to keep a candidate (e.g. 15 or 19  for 1.1)
it would require the two bordering candidates (e.g. 14 and 16 for 15, or 18 and 20 for 19)
in two bordering cells (e.g. 1.2 and 2.1.).
This is true for 19 but not for 15, hence 19 stays but 15 gets eliminated.